# Rider multiline statement alignment: How to change the default alignment?

Tags: rider

I cannot figure out how to tell Rider not to align the lines of a multiline statement. Instead of this (what Rider does by default):

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello " +
                  "World!");
var result = 1 +
             2 +
             3;
```

I want this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello " +
    "World!");
var result = 1 +
    2 +
    3;
```

Which setting do I need to set to achieve my goal? If not in Rider: Is there any .editorconfig setting I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you'd need these 2 settings here

[image]

and if you prefer to leave your operators on the same line - another one.

[image]

Comment: @Morse which links?